# prop-types oneOf allows all strings

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

```
export default function New(props: any) {
const { orientation } = props
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
        {orientation === 'horizontal' ? <HorizontalNew {...props} /> : <VerticalNew {...props} />
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
New.propTypes = {
orientation: PropTypes.oneOf(['vertical', 'horizontal'])}
```

Hi there!,
I tried to search about the function oneOf of propTypes but in every place says that you can define there the strings that you want to validate so in this sutiation i would spect that orientation only allow "Vertical" or "Horizontal" but is taking all the string's value, i can literally use any strings and works.
Is that any kind of bug or i'm missing something?
Thanks!

PS1: Sorry for my bad english

PS2: Versions: prop-types: 15.7.2, react: 16.9.0

Comment: do you have any consol errors when you pass different values than defined ones ?

Comment: Nothing, the page render the same with 'randomString' or 'horizontal', i mean is not a critic error, i can keep working on the view but the main idea is to avoid future errors

Comment: I'm able to replicate and fix it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to using the minified `production` build of React, vs the `development` build. Using the minified `production` build will suppress warnings. To see the warnings, use the `development` build of React.

Here are two examples, using the `development` build (with error), and the `production` build (with ***no*** error).

**Development**

```js
const HorizontalNew = () => 'Horizontal'
const VerticalNew = () => 'VerticalNew'

const New = (props) => {
  const { orientation } = props
  return (
    <div>
      {orientation === 'horizontal' ?
        <HorizontalNew {...props} /> :
        <VerticalNew {...props} />
      }
    </div>
  )
}

New.propTypes = {
  orientation: PropTypes.oneOf(['vertical', 'horizontal'])
}

ReactDOM.render(<New orientation="diagonal"/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prop-types/15.7.2/prop-types.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

**Production**

```js
const HorizontalNew = () => 'Horizontal'
const VerticalNew = () => 'VerticalNew'

const New = (props) => {
  const { orientation } = props
  return (
    <div>
      {orientation === 'horizontal' ?
        <HorizontalNew {...props} /> :
        <VerticalNew {...props} />
      }
    </div>
  )
}

New.propTypes = {
  orientation: PropTypes.oneOf(['vertical', 'horizontal'])
}

ReactDOM.render(<New orientation="diagonal"/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prop-types/15.7.2/prop-types.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: That could be, but just a question, if i'm using npm and i created the react project with npx create-react-app (that comes with a npm "start" script), isn't that script a DEV Mode Start?
Thanks a lot for your answer and your time

Comment: I'm able to replicate now and to fix, thanks a lot!!

Comment: Was the issue related to the env build? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, was related and i set up wrong something in the scripts, is there any way to the IDE show the allowed prop-type on oneOf (like string : { "some string" || {"other string"}) or only i can see that in the console log? Sorry for keep bothering

Comment: There might be an IDE plugin to do this, but I'm not aware of any. The only method I'm aware of is using a type checker like TypeScript, or Flow.